# How to get count of hotel on max date in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

In tableau file I have applied date range in the reports but I want the count of hotels  is something like:

```
Hotelid        Dateid
    200           20180101
    200           20180102
    200           20180301
    300           20180101
    300           20180102
    300           20180103
    400           20180103
    400           20181231
    500           20181231


Suppose date range filter  is applied from 20180101 to 20181231. 
In this case I need to count the hotels
 on maxdate of date range (20181231) and it should display 2.
```

.

Comment: Please provide the names of the fields you have and what data they should contain so we are all on the same page.

Comment: @luke B I have updated the question with an example.